# Fill an array diagonally

Tags: c++

I have following program. with Input 3 5

```
3 rows
5 growth of numbers
```

The output should be:

```
1    2    4    7    10
3    5    8    11   13
6    9    12   14   15
```

But my program gives:

```
1    2    3    4    5
    6    7    8    9   10
   11   12   13   14   15
```

Here is what I have tried so far

```
int main() {
    int n, m, c = 0;
    cin >> n >> m;
    int a[n][m];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            a[i][j] = ++c;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << setw(4) << a[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong or missing?

About the spaces: *Can't find reason for such behavior(first spaces are ignored), displayed on screenshot. Tried to run in different IDE's with different compilers and had such problem only in testing system.*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming, but about using a site of test system

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it fails only when printing result to you in the browser (e.g first spaces in tag are skipped). Just fix everything else and it will work. Note, you have different numbers printed

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to use tab instead.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, m, c = 0;

    cin >> n >> m;

    int *a  = new int[n * m];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            a[i * n + j] = ++c;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << "\t" << a[i * n + j];
        cout << endl;
    }
    delete[] a;
    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Can't remember how I solved this problem in secondary school, but with **n less than m**, the following code works:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void nextij(long n,long m,long& i,long& j) {
    if (i==n-1) { //bottom row
        if (j<n-1) { //in the left square
            j = i+j+1;
            i = 0;
        }
        else { //out of the left square
            i = j-(n-1)+1;
            j = m-1;
        }
    }
    else { //other rows
        if (j==0) { //left most column
            j = i+1;
            i = 0;
        }
        else { //other columns
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    long n = 3;
    long m = 5;
    long a[3][5];  

    long i = 0;
    long j = 0;
    long c = 1;

    while (c<=n*m) {
        a[i][j] = c;        
        nextij(n,m,i,j);
        c++;        
    }

    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<m; j++)
            cout <<a[i][j] <<" ";
        cout <<endl;
    }
}

/*
output:
1 2 4 7 10 
3 5 8 11 13 
6 9 12 14 15 
*/
```